# Parallelism between number and function, and the counterpart of periods number in functions.

Tags: complex-analysis, number-theory, algebraic-geometry

There is parallelism between number and function: rational number, algebraic number, transcendental number correspond to rational function, algebraic number, transcendental number. What function is the counterpart of periods number? Modular function,or automorphic function?